# C - address of matrix as an argument in function

Tags: c, matrix

I have this header:

```
#define SIZE 4
typedef float matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
typedef struct {
     char *name;
     matrix *mat;
} matRec;
void printMat(matrix *);
void read_mat(matrix , float []);
```

declaration in the main:

```
matrix m[6];
matRec mats[6] = {
    {"MAT_A", &m[0]},
    {"MAT_B", &m[1]},
    {"MAT_C", &m[2]},
    {"MAT_D", &m[3]}, 
    {"MAT_E", &m[4]}, 
    {"MAT_F", &m[5]}
};
struct {
    char *name;
    void (*func)();
} cmd[] = {
    {"read_mat", read_mat},
    {"not_valid", NULL}
};
```

this is also part of my main:

```
(*(cmd[func].func))(&mats[matrixx].mat, num);
printMat(mats[matrixx].mat);
```

my printMat function in the main:

```
void printMat(matrix *matrx) {
    int i,j; 
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%7f  ", matrx[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and the read_mat function (in another file):

```
void read_mat(matrix matrx, float num[]) {
     int i, j, count = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             matrx[i][j] = num[count];
             count++;
         }
     }
}
```

My purpose is to send an address of my matrix from array: mats, with array of float numbers, insert them, and print the matrix with another function. I have difficulties in sending the address. The read_mat function does "work", but with a copy of matrix(in the scope of the function), then obviously prints matrix with only zeros. I don't understand how to write the right types of arguments with pointers in declaration of function. Any other combination of * gives error. THANKS

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: I don't have a broken code. Not a warning. I did not asked for new code. I posted the relevant code for understanding my problem. I don't understand how to make declarations of functions with pointers, and just asking for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess few of the type information would help you. Here by saying this

```
matrix m[6];
```

You are basically declaring

```
float m[6][SIZE][SIZE];
```

And then type of `m[0]` is nothing but `float [SIZE][SIZE]` or `matrix`.

So when I pass it's address to a function it would be

```
somefun(&m[0]);
```

You would declare and use it like this

```
   ..somefun(matrix *t){
      for(int i = 0; i< SIZE; i++)
        for(int j =0 ; j< SIZE; j++)
          printf("%lf",(*t)[i][j]);  
    ..
   }
```